# deploying web application to azure scaleset using custom script extension and Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-vm-scale-set

To deploy a web application to azure scale set there are 2 basic way

1) Immutable VHDs but this I fell is inefficient as waiting 24 min for each build is unacceptable.

2) Custom script extension seems to a possibility but not sure I would used this as part of CD in Azure Devops and deploy my build artifact to Azure Scaleset

Answer (score 0):

Here are tutorials about installing applications in virtual machine scale sets with the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-install-apps-cli) or [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-install-apps-powershell).

This tutorial shows how to:

- Automatically install applications to your scale set
- Use the Azure Custom Script Extension
- Update a running application on a scale set

You can refer to these tutorials for details. In addition,here is a [template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-vmss-custom-script-windows/) about deploying a Windows VM Scale Set with a Custom Script Extension. Hope this helps.